# Redis Server is not getting Refreshed

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-rest, spring-data-redis

I'm using redis in my springboot rest application to store cache. But the problem I'm facing is once it is stored in redis my api only hits the redis not the database. I've added time out property it didn't work. I've tried CacheManager to get the cache and call CacheEvict to clear the cache and then CachePut to put the data again, but it didn't work. These are the things I've tried so far. I wanted my redis cache to refresh after a given time set by me. Any advice on this? Here is my code below:

```
package com.dg.repo;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import com.dg.entity.FlightEntity;

public interface FlightRepo extends JpaRepository<FlightEntity, String> {
    
    @Query(value="select distinct txtFlightName\r\n"
            + "from {test-schema}flights", nativeQuery = true)
    List<String> getAllFlights();
    
    @Query(value="select distinct txtFlightName from {test-schema}flights \r\n"
            + "where txtFlightName LIKE %:flightname%",nativeQuery = true)
    List<String> getListofFlights(@Param("flightname")String flightname);
    
    @Query(value="select distinct txtBookingCode,txtFlightName from {test-schema}flights \r\n"
            + "where txtFlightName LIKE %:flightname%",nativeQuery = true)
    List<FlightEntity> getFlightEntity(@Param("flightname")String flightname);

}
```

```
package com.dg.repo;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Function;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Example;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.HashOperations;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.FluentQuery.FetchableFluentQuery;

import com.dg.entity.FlightEntity;

public abstract class FlightRepoImpl implements FlightRepo {
    
    RedisTemplate template;
    
    HashOperations hashOperations;
    
    

    public FlightRepoImpl(RedisTemplate template, HashOperations hashOperations) {
        super();
        this.template = template;
        this.hashOperations = template.opsForHash();
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> getAllFlights() {
        return hashOperations.values("FlightModel");
    }
    
    @Override
    public List<String> getListofFlights(String flightname) {
        return (List<String>) hashOperations.get("FlightModel", flightname);
    }

}
```

```
package com.dg.service;

import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;

import com.dg.model.FlightModel;
import com.dg.repo.FlightRepo;

public class FlightService {
    
    @Autowired
    FlightRepo flightRepo;
    
    @Autowired
    ModelMapper modelMapper;
    
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 50000)
    @Caching(evict = {@CacheEvict(value="getFlightList", key="#flightname")})
    public FlightModel getFlightByFlightName(String flightName)
    {
```

```
package com.dg.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public class FlightModel implements Serializable{
    
    private List<Object> listofflightname;

    public List<Object> getListofflightname() {
        return listofflightname;
    }

    public void setListofflightname(List<Object> listofflightname) {
        this.listofflightname = listofflightname;
    }
    
    

}
```

```
package com.dg.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class FlightEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name="txtBookingCode")
    private String bookingCode;
    
    @Column(name="txtFlightName")
    private String flightname;


    public String getBookingCode() {
        return bookingCode;
    }


    public void setBookingCode(String bookingCode) {
        this.bookingCode = bookingCode;
    }


    public String getFlightname() {
        return flightname;
    }


    public void setFlightname(String flightname) {
        this.flightname = flightname;
    }
    
    

}
```

```
package com.dg.config;



import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisClusterConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.redis.repository.configuration.EnableRedisRepositories;

import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig;

@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories
@Profile("test")
public class RedisConfig {
    
    @Value("${spring.redis.cluster.nodes}")
    private String nodesProperty;
    
    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory()
    {
        JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
        poolConfig.setMinIdle(2);
        poolConfig.setMaxIdle(5);
        poolConfig.setMaxTotal(20);
        poolConfig.setEvictorShutdownTimeoutMillis(10000);
        
        String [] nodesArray=nodesProperty.split(",");
        List<String> nodes = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(nodesArray));
        
        RedisClusterConfiguration configuration=new RedisClusterConfiguration(nodes);
        configuration.setMaxRedirects(100);
        JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory(configuration);
        connectionFactory.setPoolConfig(poolConfig);
        return connectionFactory;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate redisTemplate()
    {
        RedisTemplate template = new RedisTemplate();
        template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        return template;
    }

}
```

```
package com.dg;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class RedisTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RedisTestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see any TTL or eviction strategy in what you've posted. The methods called on `poolConfig` seem to handle the connection pool for Jedis only. You mention `@CacheEvict` in your text but your code doesn't use it.

Comment: No, I've removed that. Because it didn't work.

Comment: In my application-test.yml file I've added spring.cache.redis.time-to-live property. It's not picking up.